# Can I view previously saved versions of a file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, history

After a freak git checkout accident I've lost some of my C# work :-P

Eclipse has a local revision history which is perfect for situations like this, but this work I am doing in Visual Studio 2010 and am having trouble finding an analogous feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if windows kept a old version by going to the file and right clicking and seeing if there is a previous version if your on vista or win 7.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a built in feature of Visual Studio (excluding the usual undo/redo functionality).

I am not aware of any add ons or extensions that provide such functionality, apart from using Source Control Management systems (which seems to have failed you in this instance), or if you have the OS [file version](http://lifehacker.com/180130/windows-vista-beta-rave--built+in-file-versioning) feature turned on.